# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction JAVA MAVEN SPRING

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

1. I've seen many replies, and none worked
2. My Config -> Maven / Spring 4 / Hibernate 4 / MySQL 5 / Eclipse Mars / JSF 2 / PrimeFaces 5 / Spring Security
3. The solution was working with old depedencies, I did a mvn update:versions and I'm trying to figure out solutions (It was working fine, but can't stand to the idea of every dependency is outdated)

Here is the error I get after submitting Login form (The whole Tomcat Trace)

```
août 23, 2015 3:40:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
août 23, 2015 3:40:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
août 23, 2015 3:40:28 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFOS: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
août 23, 2015 3:40:29 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFOS: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Aug 23 03:40:29 WAT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
août 23, 2015 3:40:29 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]
août 23, 2015 3:40:29 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]
août 23, 2015 3:40:29 AM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFOS: You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.2.RELEASE
août 23, 2015 3:40:29 AM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFOS: Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.0.2.RELEASE
août 23, 2015 3:40:29 AM org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser parse
INFOS: Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false.
août 23, 2015 3:40:30 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFOS: Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')' for /pages/secure/**
août 23, 2015 3:40:30 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFOS: Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /pages/unsecure/**
août 23, 2015 3:40:30 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFOS: Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')' for /**
août 23, 2015 3:40:30 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFOS: Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /javax.faces.resource/**
août 23, 2015 3:40:30 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFOS: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
août 23, 2015 3:40:31 AM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFOS: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
août 23, 2015 3:40:31 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFOS: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
août 23, 2015 3:40:32 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.0.Final}
août 23, 2015 3:40:32 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
août 23, 2015 3:40:32 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
août 23, 2015 3:40:32 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
août 23, 2015 3:40:32 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFOS: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge1379bojaf0l1f5utew|a1c6cda, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge1379bojaf0l1f5utew|a1c6cda, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/test, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 2, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
août 23, 2015 3:40:33 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
août 23, 2015 3:40:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
août 23, 2015 3:40:36 AM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFOS: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3f356487, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@45d89c1c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6bc624bd, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3e1b9cab, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2a9ed6b3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2b278780, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@719ead95, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@138299c9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4ff5ee44, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@58f96bbd, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5c8f8732, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5b4411bb, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3ba34359]
août 23, 2015 3:40:36 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFOS: Checking whether login URL '/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml' is accessible with your configuration
août 23, 2015 3:40:36 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFOS: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8304 ms
août 23, 2015 3:40:37 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFOS: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) pour le contexte «/potool»
août 23, 2015 3:40:37 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFOS: JSF1048 : Présence d’annotations PostConstruct/PreDestroy  Les méthodes de beans gérés marquées avec ces annotations auront des annotations dites traitées.
août 23, 2015 3:40:38 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFOS: Monitoring file:/C:/Users/ceo/Desktop/WorkSpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/primefaces/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
août 23, 2015 3:40:38 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFOS: Running on PrimeFaces 5.2
août 23, 2015 3:40:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
août 23, 2015 3:40:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
août 23, 2015 3:40:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 18107 ms
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at managedController.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession(HibernateTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:445)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 91 more
```

Here is my applicationContext :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- Package needed to be scanned for annotation --> <context:component-scan base-package="spring"/> <context:component-scan base-package="spring.dao.CustomerDAO"/> <!-- Use annotation for configuration--> <context:annotation-config/> <context:spring-configured/>

<!-- Data Source Declaration --> <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" /> </bean>

<!-- Session Factory Declaration --> <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>spring.model</value>
            <value>spring.service</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property> </bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations --> <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined --> <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
     </bean> </beans>
```

Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>PrimeFaces Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring Security Facelets Tag Library -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Declare Spring configuration file location -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
 <!--   <listener>
          <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> -->

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/pages/secure/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You have to learn to read stacktraces. Here's the relevant part to read and search on internet: nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext

Comment: If I didn't "learn" reading before reading, how would I resume that TITLE of QUESTION ?

Comment: Basically, your problem is that you're missing a dependency. Add the proper dependency and execute your application one more time. All the other files (web.xml, applicationContext, etc) are pointless in order to solve this problem.

Comment: I can't add my POM here due to the large post, the depedency spring-orm containing this transactionmanager is on the POM and is downloaded, along with all hibernate components.

Comment: Uh... Okay, seems that you haven't understood anything. The problem: you're missing a library where the class `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext` is located. Check the library that contains this class. Add the proper dependency of this library in your pom.xml file. Re execute the project. Period.

Comment: Seems you've got nothing of what I said .. uh .. The TransactionApi is in hibernate-core depedency and IS ALREADY in pom and in the project

Comment: Seems that you still don't understand. No matter what you say about your project, the stacktrace speaks for itself: the library is **missing**. Make sure that when you package your war the library is inside WEB-INF/lib folder. Otherwise, it's simply not there.

Comment: Please list of all jars with version from your war application in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stacktrace indicates that the `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext` isn't in the web app classpath. This class is in *hibernate-core* 4 library.

There are several ways to include it in the classpath as you can see at the [tomcat documentation section Class Loader definitions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions).

Due to you are using maven I suggest you to set scope *compile* for the library dependency to be sure that it will be included in your webapp lib folder. Check is defined like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also check the web app has the standard layout folder. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) to know how it looks and the final structure of the war package. Be sure you don't override any configuration related to lib folder in your *maven-war-plugin* because by default tomcat will look for libraries in *WEB-INF/lib* folder of war package.

Comment: Hello, the solution a little related to that, the unfound class is not in 4.3.11, the last version having that class is the 4.0.1. I found that in the hibernate website. Thank you

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa for welcome!, but you do not limit yourself to use hibernate-core 4.0.1 because the unfounded class actually is in the latest 4.3 version. The next link is the source code of hibernate 4.3.11, you will find the class over there https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same exception but resolved it with the following configuration.

My POM.xml:

```
<properties>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

My servlet-context.xml configuration (Mentioned only hibernate related config):

```
<beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>your pojo name along with package</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```